# HTML Mail background is white cause of signature

Tags: html, css, signature

I have created an e-mail-signature in HTML and I am using it with the native Apple Mail-app on iPhone.

I am using Dark Mode, too, but sadly, the background of my emails turns white if I use my signature. I don't know what is causing this.

Is there a way to put the background transparent so it won't be white and turns black text to white (automatically done by the mail client, here apple mail)

Here is my signature :

```
<div>
    <style>
        .sh-src a {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</div>
<br />
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="sh-src" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: separate; margin: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <!---->
                    <td valign="top" style="padding: 0px 17px 0px 1px; vertical-align: top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); white-space: nowrap; margin: 1px;">My name</p>
                                    <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); margin: 1px;">My function</p>
                                    <!---->
                                    <!---->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <!---->
                                <td valign="middle" colspan="3" style="padding: 3px 1px 0px 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="22" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a href="linkedin url" target="_blank">
                                                        <img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/linkedin/round-outlined/007bff.png" alt="" width="22" height="22" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 22px;" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="2" style="padding: 0px 0px 1px;"></td>
                                            <td width="22" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a href="insta url" target="_blank">
                                                        <img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/instagram/round-outlined/007bff.png" alt="" width="22" height="22" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 22px;" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="2" style="padding: 0px 0px 1px;"></td>
                                            <td width="22" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a href="YouTube url" target="_blank">
                                                        <img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/youtube/round-outlined/007bff.png" alt="" width="22" height="22" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 22px;" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="2" style="padding: 0px 0px 1px;"></td>
                                            <td width="22" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a href="imdb url" target="_blank">
                                                        <img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/imdb/round-outlined/007bff.png" alt="" width="22" height="22" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 22px;" />
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="2" style="padding: 0px 0px 1px;"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 1px 0px 0px; border-right-width: 2px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-color: rgb(0, 123, 255);"></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding: 0px 1px 0px 17px; vertical-align: top;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="middle" style="padding: 1px 5px 1px 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;"><img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/email/default/007bff.png" alt="" width="18" height="18" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 18px;" /></p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 135) !important; padding: 1px 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a
                                                        href="mailto:mail"
                                                        target="_blank"
                                                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); text-decoration: none !important;"
                                                    >
                                                        <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); text-decoration: none !important;">
                                                            mail.com
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="middle" style="padding: 1px 5px 1px 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;"><img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/mobile/default/007bff.png" alt="" width="18" height="18" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 18px;" /></p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 135) !important; padding: 1px 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a
                                                        href="tel:phone"
                                                        target="_blank"
                                                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); text-decoration: none !important;"
                                                    >
                                                        <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); text-decoration: none !important;">
                                                            My phone
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!---->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="middle" style="padding: 1px 5px 1px 0px; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;"><img src="https://signaturehound.com/api/v1/png/website/default/007bff.png" alt="" width="18" height="18" style="display: block; border: 0px; max-width: 18px;" /></p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td
                                                style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(0, 123, 254) !important; font-weight: 700; padding: 1px 0px; vertical-align: middle;"
                                            >
                                                <p style="margin: 1px;">
                                                    <a
                                                        href="domain.com"
                                                        target="_blank"
                                                        style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(0, 123, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none !important;"
                                                    >
                                                        <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(0, 123, 255); font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none !important;">
                                                            domain.com
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0px 1px 14px 0px; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 123, 255);"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px 1px 0px 0px;">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also when I write the mail, the signature looks good as it should looks but not when it’s sent :

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem, seems like both of us are using signaturehound.com to generate that signature mail. Have you found the solution?

Comment: Still no solution found…

Comment: I receive mails from namecheap, google, aws, vercel etc. All of them display this hardcoded white background because of using images. I guess if these top tier companies cant find a workaround, this is either a bug or a feature created by apple for some very unusual reason. We'll have to leave it like this